# tkinter: How to create a class object with a function called by a Button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I created an entry where I enter some value. By clicking the <kbd>submit</kbd> button I want the function `create_object` to get the `entry` value, then an object of the class `Test_Class` is created with the gotten value as a parameter and the object is returned.

But obviously that object has not yet been created and therefore cannot be accessed, right? How do I actually create a class object and then access it?

```
from tkinter import *

class Test_Class:
    def __init__(self, parameter ):
        self.parameter = parameter

root = Tk()

def create_object():
    parameter = entry.get()
    object = Test_Class(parameter)
    return object

entry = Entry(root, width=30)
entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=create_object)
submit.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you said `print(object)` and checked if thats what you want?

Comment: Just tried it. I found out that ```object``` is a built in class. so i changed it to simply ```a```. when I try to access (or print) a it says that a is not defined which makes sense since 'a' is a local variable only inside that function.

Comment: You need to make the instance of `Test_Class` global in order to be accessed else where in your program.  Anything returned by the callback of a button is discarded.

Comment: Like you have to say `global a`, in your case

Comment: `tkinter` ignores an value that's returned by a `Button` callback function — so you have to save the value somewhere _in the function_. The easiest way if by using a `global` variable (which you will need to declare at the beginning of the function's body).

Comment: Alright thanks. I thought using global variables makes the code kind of messy. like if I wanted to use that function more than once. So thank you but if you can think of a more 'clean' way, then let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply stop using procedural programming altogether, and then you don't have to worry about scope issues. All I did was turn your code into classes and refactor it a little so you can test your write and read results.

Another simple change was: instead of worrying about things that may or may not exist, I simply created something that definitely exists to hold the aforementioned things, and you can just loop through that to find out what exists.

```
import tkinter as tk
from typing import *

class Test_Class:
    def __init__(self, parameter ):
        self.parameter = parameter
        
    def __str__(self):
        #allows us to call print on the entire class to print self.parameter value
        return self.parameter

#extend the root
class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)            
        #you don't have to "strict type" this. I just did, cause I do
        self.param_objects:List[Test_Class] = []
        
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        #unless you intend for your script to modify or delete these buttons, there is no need for a reference
        tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.create_pobjs).grid(row=1, column=0)
        tk.Button(self, text="Check", command=self.print_pobjs).grid(row=1, column=1)
        
    def create_pobjs(self):
        #create a new Test_Class instance
        self.param_objects.append(Test_Class(self.entry.get()))
        
    def print_pobjs(self):
        for param in self.param_objects:
            #call print on the entire Test_Class instance
            print(param)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Root().mainloop()
```